# How to reset or unchecked radio button if have changes on dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I'm trying to resetting or unchecked a set of four radio buttons if there is a changes on my dropdown. I my case below after I made changes on dropdown value to null, the date dropdown is reset, however radio button for time is not unchecked.

[image]

**I have tried below solution but not help.**

1) `$('input[name="am11"]').prop('checked', false);`

2) `$('input[name="am11"]').attr('checked', false);`

3) `$("#abc").attr('disabled', true);`

```js
// Append Value at 3rd Step according to selection on 2nd Step
for (i = 0; i < nodeslist.length; i++) { 
 $("#nodes").append($("<option>", {
  value: valuenodeslist[i],
  text: nodeslist[i]
 }));
}

$("#nodes").change(function() { //This if for step 3

  resetVals();  //applied 06.08.19

  // Enabled-disable 3rd Step
  if ($("#nodes").val() == "") {
    //below are the step 4 if step 3 value is null
    $('input[name="radiotime"]').prop('checked', false); //either one
    $("#abc").attr('disabled', true); //either one

  } else {
    $("#abc").removeAttr("disabled");
  }

 function resetVals() {
 $("input:radio").each(function() {
 $(this)[0].checked = false;
   });
 }                //applied 06.08.19

});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="nodes" class="custom-select2 form-control" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple" disabled>
 <option value="" disabled>-- NODE --</option>
</select>
    <div class="row mb-20">

      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" id="abc" data-toggle="buttons" disabled>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                    <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="pm3" autocomplete="off"> 3PM
                </label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                    <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="am11" autocomplete="off"> 11AM
                </label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                    <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="pm10" autocomplete="off"> 10PM
                </label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                    <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="am2" autocomplete="off"> 2AM
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the `#step3`?

Comment: Are you sure the code is being reached ? Add a ```console.log('test');``` before the if statement to see if it's being reached.

Comment: `$('input[name="radiotime"]').removeAttr("checked");`

Comment: Yes it is been tested before with console.log, I received a value for each time I selected.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#checked `checked` *A Boolean attribute which, if present, indicates that this radio button is the currently selected one in the group* - note **if present** - it's a value-less attribute, ie `<input checked` not `<input checked=true` so as long as the attribute exists, it is true.

Comment: paste all your html code (two select input)

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to reset the checked attribute because when you select a particular radio button, there is no `checked='true'` attribute added on the HTML DOM (you can check it on developer tools also).

When you select a radio button, we see that the checked value set to true in the object itself, but not on the DOM; so when drop down is changed, we just iterate through all the radio button options and reset the values;

Working **snippet below**:

```js
function resetVals() {
  $("input:radio").each(function() {
    $(this)[0].checked = false;
    //console.log($(this)); //print id element
  });
}

$("#mySelection").change(function() {
  resetVals();
});

/*
$("input[name='radiotime']").click(function() {
  //console.log($(this)[0].id, " and ", $(this)[0].value, $(this));
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <select id='mySelection'>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <br/><br/>

  <div class="row mb-20">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" id="abc">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary"> </label>
      <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="pm3"> 3PM

      <span>&nbsp;</span>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary"> </label>
      <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="am11"> 11AM

      <span>&nbsp;</span>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="pm10"> 10PM

      <span>&nbsp;</span>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="radiotime" id="am2"> 2AM
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I will try it first and let you know.

Comment: I just run your additional codes but not solve. I has amend my original post above with your code implementation. Is that true?

Comment: The problem still unable to reset the selection if I made a change in dropdown. It is need to select somewhere to make ke option button deselected.

Comment: Just to inform that my dropdown data `<option>` is controlled by JS, I am not put the data at HTML page.

Comment: can you update the question with your complete code... i can help you through the issue; the example i shared worked separately, so it should work unless there is a dependency somewhere